# Chef - Not able to set registry_key value being passed from ruby_block

Tags: chef-infra

I have recipe , where I am basically trying to update windows registry using `registry_key` chef resource . I have to make some conditional checks on existing value before updating it & hence I am using `ruby_block` for doing so.
However I am facing an issue where in node attributes are not getting evaluated lazily , I am using this lazy node attr for setting registry value.

*For more detailed info , I am pasting a full recipe code here for analysis*

```
# Cookbook:: myCookbook
# Recipe:: myrecipe-rectify-java-param-tomcat-service
# In brief , this recipe does simple things 
### 1 Fetch existing value of registry(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\ABC\Parameters\Java)
### 2 Check if it has '-Dsun.net.maxDatagramSockets' in it , if yes then update its value , if no then add -Dsun.net.maxDatagramSockets=1024 entry in it
### 3 Update registry(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\ABC\Parameters\Java)


node.default['myCookbook']['options_value'] = nil
node.default['myCookbook']['existing_java_key_value'] = nil

#1 
ruby_block "fetching JAVA options of ABC tomcat service" do
  block do
    node.override['myCookbook']['existing_java_key_value'] = registry_get_values('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\ABC\Parameters\Java', :x86_64)
    node['myCookbook']['existing_java_key_value'].each{|e| 
      if e[:name] == "Options"
          node.override['myCookbook']['options_value'] = e[:data]
          Chef::Log.info("1--- herrreeee options value is ")
          Chef::Log.info(node['myCookbook']['options_value'])
      end
    }
  end
  action :run
end

#2
ruby_block "modifying JAVA reg key value through ruby block" do
  block do
    Chef::Log.info("2--- here in ruby lblockck ")
    Chef::Log.info("2.1 --- options_value is ")
  
    doesItemExist = false
      indexis = 0
    node['myCookbook']['options_value'].each_with_index { |item,index| 
      if (item.include? "-Dsun.net.maxDatagramSockets")
        Chef::Log.info("item is "+item)
        doesItemExist = true
            indexis = index
        break
      end
    }
    if (doesItemExist)
      Chef::Log.info("hey registry already has maxDatagramSockets thing at index #{indexis} , so need to replace it")
        node.override['myCookbook']['options_value'][indexis]="-Dsun.net.maxDatagramSockets=#{node['myCookbook']['abcservice']['max_datagram_socket']}"
    else
      Chef::Log.info("Seems it is first time we are adding maxDatagramsocket")
      node.override['myCookbook']['options_value'].insert(-1, "-Dsun.net.maxDatagramSockets=#{node['myCookbook']['abcservice']['max_datagram_socket']}")
    end
    Chef::Log.info("2.2 ##### #{node['myCookbook']['options_value']} #####")
    Chef::Log.info(node['myCookbook']['options_value'])
  end
  action :run
end

#3
registry_key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\ABC\Parameters\Java' do
  values [{
    name: 'Options',
    type: :multi_string,
    #data: options_value
    data: lazy { node[myCookbook][:options_value] }
  }]
  action :create
end
```

Error , which I receive when running this recipe through chef solo , I face an issue at Step#3 (i.e setting registry with updated value) , **it seems that `lazy` node attribute `node[myCookbook][:options_value]` is still having `nil` value & doesn't persist the value , which I am setting in `ruby_block`**

```
[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] DEBUG: Converging node AMD-MYVM-0
Recipe: myCookbook::myrecipe-rectify-java-param-tomcat-service[0m
  * ruby_block[fetching JAVA options of ABC tomcat service] action run[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] INFO: Processing ruby_block[fetching JAVA options of ABC tomcat service] action run (myCookbook::myrecipe-rectify-java-param-tomcat-service line 29)
[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] INFO: 1--- herrreeee options value is 
[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] INFO: ["-XX:+PrintGCDetails,", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled,", "-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m,", "-Dabc.home=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_HOME\\\\TESTCOMPANY\\\\ABC\\\\tomcat\\\\..,", "-Dabc.host=AMD-MYVM-0,", "-Dcatalina.base=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_HOME\\\\TESTCOMPANY\\\\ABC\\\\tomcat,", "-Dcatalina.home=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_HOME\\\\TESTCOMPANY\\\\ABC\\\\tomcat,", "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_HOME\\\\TESTCOMPANY\\\\ABC\\\\tomcat\\\\endorsed,", "-Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_HOME\\\\TESTCOMPANY\\\\ABC\\\\tomcat\\\\temp,", "-Darchaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls=file:///D:/TESTCOMPANY_HOME/TESTCOMPANY/Properties/application.properties,file:///D:/TESTCOMPANY_HOME/TESTCOMPANY/ABC/conf/overrides.properties,", "-DFileCacheSharedRootDir=\\\\\\\\127.0.0.1\\\\Repositories\\\\data\\\\cache,", "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_CONFIGS\\\\ABC\\\\conf\\\\log4j2.xml,", "-Xdebug,", "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8969,server=y,suspend=n,", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote,", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7969,", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false,", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false,", "-Dsun.net.maxDatagramSockets=1028,", "-XX:-CreateMinidumpOnCrash"]
[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] INFO: ruby_block[fetching JAVA options of ABC tomcat service] called

    [32m- execute the ruby block fetching JAVA options of ABC tomcat service[0m
[0m  * ruby_block[modifying JAVA reg key value through ruby block] action run[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] INFO: Processing ruby_block[modifying JAVA reg key value through ruby block] action run (myCookbook::myrecipe-rectify-java-param-tomcat-service line 43)
[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] INFO: 2--- here in ruby lblockck 
[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] INFO: 2.1 --- options_value is 
[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] INFO: item is -Dsun.net.maxDatagramSockets=1028,
[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] INFO: now item is -Dsun.net.maxDatagramSockets=1028,
[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] INFO: hey registry already has maxDatagramSockets thing at index 18 , so need to replace it
[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] INFO: 2.2 ##### ["-XX:+PrintGCDetails,", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled,", "-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m,", "-Dabc.home=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_HOME\\\\TESTCOMPANY\\\\ABC\\\\tomcat\\\\..,", "-Dabc.host=AMD-MYVM-0,", "-Dcatalina.base=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_HOME\\\\TESTCOMPANY\\\\ABC\\\\tomcat,", "-Dcatalina.home=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_HOME\\\\TESTCOMPANY\\\\ABC\\\\tomcat,", "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_HOME\\\\TESTCOMPANY\\\\ABC\\\\tomcat\\\\endorsed,", "-Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_HOME\\\\TESTCOMPANY\\\\ABC\\\\tomcat\\\\temp,", "-Darchaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls=file:///D:/TESTCOMPANY_HOME/TESTCOMPANY/Properties/application.properties,file:///D:/TESTCOMPANY_HOME/TESTCOMPANY/ABC/conf/overrides.properties,", "-DFileCacheSharedRootDir=\\\\\\\\127.0.0.1\\\\Repositories\\\\data\\\\cache,", "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_CONFIGS\\\\ABC\\\\conf\\\\log4j2.xml,", "-Xdebug,", "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8969,server=y,suspend=n,", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote,", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7969,", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false,", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false,", "-Dsun.net.maxDatagramSockets=1024", "-XX:-CreateMinidumpOnCrash"] #####
[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] INFO: ["-XX:+PrintGCDetails,", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled,", "-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m,", "-Dabc.home=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_HOME\\\\TESTCOMPANY\\\\ABC\\\\tomcat\\\\..,", "-Dabc.host=AMD-MYVM-0,", "-Dcatalina.base=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_HOME\\\\TESTCOMPANY\\\\ABC\\\\tomcat,", "-Dcatalina.home=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_HOME\\\\TESTCOMPANY\\\\ABC\\\\tomcat,", "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_HOME\\\\TESTCOMPANY\\\\ABC\\\\tomcat\\\\endorsed,", "-Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_HOME\\\\TESTCOMPANY\\\\ABC\\\\tomcat\\\\temp,", "-Darchaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls=file:///D:/TESTCOMPANY_HOME/TESTCOMPANY/Properties/application.properties,file:///D:/TESTCOMPANY_HOME/TESTCOMPANY/ABC/conf/overrides.properties,", "-DFileCacheSharedRootDir=\\\\\\\\127.0.0.1\\\\Repositories\\\\data\\\\cache,", "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=D:\\\\TESTCOMPANY_CONFIGS\\\\ABC\\\\conf\\\\log4j2.xml,", "-Xdebug,", "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8969,server=y,suspend=n,", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote,", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7969,", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false,", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false,", "-Dsun.net.maxDatagramSockets=1024", "-XX:-CreateMinidumpOnCrash"]
[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] INFO: ruby_block[modifying JAVA reg key value through ruby block] called

    [32m- execute the ruby block modifying JAVA reg key value through ruby block[0m
[0m  * registry_key[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\ABC\Parameters\Java] action create[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] INFO: Processing registry_key[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\ABC\Parameters\Java] action create (myCookbook::myrecipe-rectify-java-param-tomcat-service line 75)

    [0m
    ================================================================================[0m
    [31mError executing action `create` on resource 'registry_key[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\ABC\Parameters\Java]'[0m
    ================================================================================[0m
    
[0m    NoMethodError[0m
    -------------[0m
    undefined method `to_a' for #<Chef::DelayedEvaluator:0x0000000009f91f10>
[0m    Did you mean?  to_s[0m
    
[0m    Resource Declaration:[0m
    ---------------------[0m
    # In D:/chef_repos_copied_from_testcompany_git/cache/cookbooks/myCookbook/recipes/myrecipe-rectify-java-param-tomcat-service.rb
[0m    
[0m     75: registry_key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\ABC\Parameters\Java' do
[0m     76:   values [{
[0m     77:     name: 'Options',
[0m     78:     type: :multi_string,
[0m     79:     #data: options_value
[0m     80:     data: lazy { node[myCookbook][:options_value] }
[0m     81:   }]
[0m     82:   action :create
[0m     83: end
[0m    
[0m    Compiled Resource:[0m
    ------------------[0m
    # Declared in D:/chef_repos_copied_from_testcompany_git/cache/cookbooks/myCookbook/recipes/myrecipe-rectify-java-param-tomcat-service.rb:75:in `from_file'
[0m    
[0m    registry_key("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\ABC\Parameters\Java") do
[0m      action [:create]
[0m      default_guard_interpreter :default
[0m      values [{:name=>"Options", :type=>:multi_string, :data=>#<Chef::DelayedEvaluator:0x0000000009f91f10@D:/chef_repos_copied_from_testcompany_git/cache/cookbooks/myCookbook/recipes/myrecipe-rectify-java-param-tomcat-service.rb:80>}]
[0m      unscrubbed_values [{:name=>"Options", :type=>:multi_string, :data=>#<Chef::DelayedEvaluator:0x0000000009f91f10@D:/chef_repos_copied_from_testcompany_git/cache/cookbooks/myCookbook/recipes/myrecipe-rectify-java-param-tomcat-service.rb:80>}]
[0m      declared_type :registry_key
[0m      cookbook_name "myCookbook"
[0m      recipe_name "myrecipe-rectify-java-param-tomcat-service"
[0m      key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Apache Software Foundation\\Procrun 2.0\\ABC\\Parameters\\Java"
[0m    end
[0m    
[0m    System Info:[0m
    ------------[0m
    chef_version=15.7.32
[0m    platform=windows
[0m    platform_version=6.3.9600
[0m    ruby=ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x64-mingw32]
[0m    program_name=C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/chef-solo
[0m    executable=C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/chef-solo[0m
    
[0m[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[0m
Running handlers:[0m
[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[0m[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Infra Client failed. 2 resources updated in 04 seconds[0m
[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to D:/chef_repos_copied_from_testcompany_git/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2021-07-08T15:48:23+05:30] DEBUG: NoMethodError: registry_key[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\ABC\Parameters\Java] (myCookbook::myrecipe-rectify-java-param-tomcat-service line 75) had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `to_a' for #<Chef::DelayedEvaluator:0x0000000009f91f10>
Did you mean?  to_s
C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/win32/registry.rb:749:in `write'
C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.7.32-universal-ming
```

I have been reading articles/posts/forums finding that chef follows 2 step pass (compile+covergence) , `lazy` can force to evaluate attrs at execution/convergence phase & all. However I am still facing this type of issue with my above recipe . I would appreciate if any one can guide me in proper direction.

Comment: Update : I discussed this with chef community over slack channel & created an issue https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/11877

Answer (score 1):

The `data` to be passed to a `:multi_string` should be a text or array. That's why the `registry_key` resource tries to perform `to_a` (convert to array) method on the value passed to `data` field. Since we are passing a `lazy` object instead of string/array, the `to_a` conversion fails.

One way to avoid using the "lazy" evaluation, is to use the `compile_time` flag in *both the* `ruby_block` resources. This will make sure that the `node['myCookbook']['options_value']` attribute will be set during compilation, and the value will be available during converge directly.

Example (note the use of `compile_time true` flag):

```rb
ruby_block "fetching JAVA options of ABC tomcat service" do
  block do
    node.override['myCookbook']['existing_java_key_value'] = registry_get_values('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\ABC\Parameters\Java', :x86_64)
    node['myCookbook']['existing_java_key_value'].each{|e| 
      if e[:name] == "Options"
        node.override['myCookbook']['options_value'] = e[:data]
        Chef::Log.info("1--- herrreeee options value is ")
        Chef::Log.info(node['myCookbook']['options_value'])
      end
    }
  end
  compile_time true
  action :run
end

registry_key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\ABC\Parameters\Java' do
  values [{
    name: 'Options',
    type: :multi_string,
    data: node['myCookbook']['options_value']
  }]
  action :create
end
```

---

**Update**

The other option could be to write the Ruby code *as-is* in the recipe and do away with the `ruby_block`s altogether (preferable IMHO). Something like:

```rb
options_value = []
foo = registry_get_values('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\ABC\Parameters\Java', :x86_64)

foo.each do |e|
  if e[:name] == "Options"
    options_value.append(e[:data])
    # and other code as necessary
  end
end

registry_key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\ABC\Parameters\Java' do
  values [{
    name: 'Options',
    type: :multi_string,
    data: options_value
  }]
  action :create
end
```

Comment: Thanks for replying on this thread . Tried with compile_time , I was getting undefined method `compile_time' for Chef::Resource::RubyBlock . Don't know why , I am using chef solo with chef_version=15.7.32.  Apart from that I still don't understand chef 2 part execution theory . For-ex in above update , why doesn't for.each loop doesn't get executed in compile phase , since it is plain ruby code .

Comment: The `foo.each` loop will run in Compile phase. If you use `puts` within loop, you will see that it appears while `Compiling Cookbooks...` and before `Converging X resources`.

Comment: I see , yeah I am getting puts print log in Compiling Cookbooks phase . I am facing one more issue . I have created multiple of such recipes for updating/adding diff jvm options of tomcat services . Now the problem is since     `existing_java_key_value` gets executed during compile phase all those recipes are getting same registry value , so the recipe , which gets executed at last in order is the only one updating registry value .

Comment: An easy way out could be to name the variables according to cookbook/recipe/purpose , e.g. `cookbook1_options_value`, if you cannot run the recipes separately.

Comment: Sorry I think , I didn't make a clear explanation . So I am facing an issue when running multiple of such recipes (1 recipe updating heapdump related jvm option , another recipe updating some other jvm param) . Here since `foo = registry_get_values('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\ABC\Parameters\Java', :x86_64)` gets executed during compilation phase for both recipes , I am always getting same value for `foo` for both recipes & because of that the recipe , which gets executed at last updates registry value.

Comment: Hypothetically. Recipe1.rb (foo = [1,2,3] , adding '4' in to registry setting it so now registry is [1,2,3,4]) .  Recipe2.rb (foo = [1,2,3] , adding '6' in to registry setting it so now registry is [1,2,3,6]) . When I run Recipe1 & Recipe2 in sequence through role file in single execution. I am expecting that at end, registry would look like [1,2,3,4,6] , however this is what I get as registry  [1,2,3,6]. Here see that registry gets updated from Recipe2 , which got executed at last in order. This is happening because for both recipes foo = [1,2,3] gets evaluated during compile phase.